# What's the meaning of the word unlike in Markdown Help Page

Tags: discussion

When I'm reading the *MarkDown* help page, I have trouble comprehending this sentence.

> Like code blocks, code spans will be displayed in a monospaced font. Markdown and HTML will not work within them. Note that, [unlike] code blocks, code spans require you to manually escape any HTML within!

I do not know clearly about what's the meaning of the word `unlike` (not the indented meaning) and the difference of `manually escape any HTML within` in code blocks and code spans.

Because I found that they both keep the html tags.

```
<h1>code block</h1>
```

---

`<h1>code spans</h1>`

both keep the tag `<h1>`

> manually escape any HTML within

In my present knowledge of `manually escape HTML within` is to remove `<h1>` manually, however we should manually remove `<h1>` both in code blocks and code spans in the example above. So where I went wrong in comprehending this sentence?

Forgive my poor English comprehension ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That passage is misleading at best. You can find the same confusion raised here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93795/editing-help-page-why-manually-escape-html

...and suggestions for changing it here: [Update the Markdown help to reflect the modern realities of Stack Exchange 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142592/update-the-markdown-help-to-reflect-the-modern-realities-of-stack-exchange-2-0/142465#142465)

We're in the middle of a bunch of changes to documentation right now, but will try to get to this page too at some point.